# How to get all the agents in the surrounding area in GISMap

Tags: anylogic

I have this one target agent, I want to get all the other agents that are within like 100 meters in GISMap. 
Is there a way that you do not need to iterate through every agent in your environment and calculate their distances to the target agent to achieve the task, because If I have 5000 agents and I want to know who are within the area every second, the calculation burden will just be too much I think. 
Thanks!

Comment: give more info: are all your agents moving? are all the agents trying to go towards the target agent? why do you need to iterate through every agent? What's the purpose of this iteration? Then we can help more effectively

Comment: Sorry my bad. All agents are moving constantly, not towards the target agent. I just want to know who's around my target agent every second, looks like the only way is to do an iteration to calculate each agent's distance with my target agent to know who is within the range.

Comment: yeah but why do you want to know who is around your target?

Comment: You can use `getAgentsInRange` to get a list of all agents within a certain distance. That avoids *you* explicitly iterating through all agents but effectively there will still be iteration going on under the covers if your real concern is performance. But don't try to prematurely optimise for performance: just try it and see the impact. (Such iterations are very fast in Java.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the logic around. Make the other agents register with your target agent when they are close enough.

Depending on the situation, this could be more efficient (but there is no guarantee).

Apart from that, there is no different logic to achieve this. So you would need to think differently: check less frequently or use a different (non GIS) condition

Comment: Thank you sir! At least now I know there is no default and special method to do this.

Comment: if it helped, please flag it as "useful" (little up arrow next to the reply) so others can find it easier in the future ;-)